# 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse'

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a method for consuming a restful GET method in Visual studio 2013, with framework 4.5. This is windows_phone_8 (targeting Phone OS 8.0) application. Here is my code.

```
static string HttpGet(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url)
                             as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                      as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I am getting a build error as follows

> 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know why it happens, the same code is working fine with Windows_application in the same environment.

**Update :** I have tried with the web client method also

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

            Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://192.168.10.73:8087/cisms/mobilews/login/userNameCheck?userName=supervisor");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data.Close();
            reader.Close();
```

Got another set of errors ...

> Error 1   'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for
>   'OpenRead' and no extension method 'OpenRead' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 3   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Update 2 :**

I have changed the code as follows, based on @Gavin' answer..

```
static async void HttpGet(string url)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        string result = null;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

But the control goes back to the calling event, from the following line

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Answer :**

I changed the code as follows and it is working now..

```
public async Task<string> httpRequest(string url)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            string received;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {

                        received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }
```

the calling part is as follows...

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string uriString = "http://192.168.10.73:8087/cisms/mobilews/login/userNameCheck?userName=supervisor";
            var response = await httpRequest(uriString);
        }
```

**Update 3:**

I have one more issue in processing POST request. The code I have tried is given below.

```
static string HttpPost(string url, string[] paramName, string[] paramVal)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url))
                                 as HttpWebRequest;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Build a string with all the params, properly encoded.
            // We assume that the arrays paramName and paramVal are
            // of equal length:
            StringBuilder paramz = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < paramName.Length; i++)
            {
                paramz.Append(paramName[i]);
                paramz.Append("=");
                paramz.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paramVal[i]));
                paramz.Append("&");
            }

            // Encode the parameters as form data:
            byte[] formData =
                UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paramz.ToString());
            req.ContentLength = formData.Length;

            // Send the request:
            using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            }

            // Pick up the response:
            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                          as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader =
                    new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

This method is having two build errors in Windows phone 8 application

> Error 1   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: More generally, often in WP8 you will try to use methods that won't work and you don't know why. That's because there are some methods that run on W8 or WinRT but not WP8. When you are confronted with some code that SHOULD work and you get an error like this, just google "your method WP8" and you'll probably find which replacement method you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP8 supports a subset of .NET Framework 4.5.

You can adapt the code variations below for your needs:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
return Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, result =>
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    ...
}
```

or

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: got group of build errors....

1 ) The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync(System.IAsyncResult, System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>)' has some invalid arguments
------------------

2 ) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.IAsyncResult'

Comment: Alternative version added just in case it helps. Both are used in a WP8 app of my own so have been tested.

Comment: Yes, partially succeeded, a small error remains "Error 2 The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>"

Comment: Now that code is not working, I have updated the question : see Update 2.

Comment: Problem is solved; answer is updated in the question itself... If you could show me, how to JSON parse it, that would be nice.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin... I have a similar issue with a POST method also. I have updated the question.

Comment: Its not working :( . Control goes to end of the function after executing "using" statement. And no result is shown.