# HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for GetResponse()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have stirred me blind on my code I have been looking at my code for hours but I don't understand why getResponse() is not being detected

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321966/system-net-httpwebrequest-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getresponse) either I didn't understand the answer or it doesn't apply to my case. I have browsed a bunch of examples and their code is almost identical to mine. Am i missing something obvious?

```
private String GetRequest(String link)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        WebResponse response = null;
        const string appId = "0000";
        const string appKey = "0000";

        try
        {

            request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(link);

            request.Headers["app_id"] = appId;
            request.Headers["app_key"] = appKey;

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            response = request.GetResponse(); // not working

            //response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e);
        }

    }
```

GetResponse() gives me the error:

> 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what project type and target framework version?

Comment: Project type = Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web and target framework version = NetCoreApp 1.1

Comment: so you are using **.net core**, and you should search code with this keyword

Comment: Alright so basically I tried to apply general c# code to .Net Core which I can't do. Is it correct I have to use HttpClient in .Net core then?